Identify movie, daughters, multiple story plots
I try to find the title for a movie but can only remember parts of the story plot.
All in all it contains multiple story lines of which one is a husband who tells fake, tragic stories to people (in bars for example). It is part of an acting class and people believe him usually. His wife thinks he is rather a boring person.
The other story lines are about dating and romance of sorts. In the end the different threads are reconciled by revealing that all the women are sisters and they visit the wedding vow renewal ceremony of their parents.
This should be maybe 5 years ago (2011), typical American blockbuster, all in English.

Sounds like Playing by Heart with Angelina Jolie, Sean Connery, Gillian Anderson (and many others), but it's from 1998.

Eleven articulate people work through affairs of the heart in L.A. Paul produces Hannah's TV cooking show, and they must move beyond gentle barbs when she wants to know about an affair of his years ago. Mark is dying of AIDS, and his mother comes to his bedside: they must talk truthfully. Men have scalded Meredith so she rebuffs Trent's charm, but he persists. The trendy, prolix Joan tries to pull the solitary Keenan into her orbit: why is he reluctant? An adulterous couple meet at hotels for evening sex, but she is unwilling for the relationship to grow. Hugh tells tall tales, usually tragic, to women in bars. By the week's end, their parallel stories converge.

The female protagonists turn out to be sisters, and they all turn up at their parents' vow renewal. Here's the trailer:




That is the one, brilliant!

@hipster1 Glad to hear, but don't forget to approve the answer (by clicking on the check mark next to it).
